# Struts 2 get custom action anotation in interceptors

Tags: struts2, annotations

Consider below action class with three action mappings. Two of them are annotated with a custom annotation `@AjaxAction`

```java
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

  @Action("action1")
  @AjaxAction  //My custom anotation
  public String action1(){    
  }    

  @Action("action2")
   public String action2(){    
    }

  @Action("action3")
  @AjaxAction  //My custom anotation
  public String action3(){    
  }    
}
```

In an interceptor I want to access the `@AjaxAction` annotation. Is there any built in support for this?!

If not can I shall read the action name with `ActionContext.getContext().getName();` and save a list of `ajaxAction` names in interceptor as an array and compare action name with this array! any better way?!

```java
private static final String[] AJAX_ACTIONS = new String[] {"action1", "action3"}

//in interceptor
String actionName = ActionContext.getContext().getName();
if (Arrays.asList(AJAX_ACTIONS).contains(actionName)) {
           // do something
        }
```

Comment: You can do like this: Class myActionClass = invocation.getAction().getClass(); for (Method method : myActionClass.getMethods()) {if(method.isAnnotationPresent(AjaxAction.class)) {//Do your work here}}

Comment: There is `AnnotationUtils` in XWork2 you can try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class YourInterceptor implements Interceptor {
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation inv) throws Exception {

Class myActionClass = inv.getAction().getClass(); 
    for (Method method : myActionClass.getMethods()) 
    {
        if(method.isAnnotationPresent(AjaxAction.class)) 
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
  return inv.invoke();
  }
  }
```

Alternative is

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.AnnotationUtils;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class YourInterceptor implements Interceptor {
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation inv) throws Exception {
 AnnotationUtils myutil = new AnnotationUtils();
    Class myActionClass = inv.getAction().getClass(); 
    for (Method method : myActionClass.getMethods()) 
    {
        if(myutil.getAnnotatedMethods(myActionClass, AjaxAction.class).contains(method))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
  return inv.invoke();
  }
 }
```

**Edit :**

To find exact executed method.

**Note:** Change `Namespace="/"` as per your configuration in `struts.xml`.

```
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher;

ActionContext context = inv.getInvocationContext();
String executedAction=context.getName();

String executedMethod=Dispatcher.getInstance().getConfigurationManager().getConfiguration().getRuntimeConfiguration().getActionConfigs().get("/").get(executedAction).getMethodName();
    if(executedMethod==null)
    {
        executedMethod="execute";
    }

for (Method method : myActionClass.getMethods()) 
    {
        if(method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(executedMethod) || method.isAnnotationPresent(Action.class)) 
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
Class myActionClass = inv.getAction().getClass();
for (Method method : myActionClass.getMethods()) 
{
     //check whether called method has annotation?
     if(method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(executedAction) && method.isAnnotationPresent(AjaxAction.class)) 
     {
            // do something
     }
 }
```

I hope this will work.

**Note:** This is just a workaround I found. <kbd>Better</kbd> way would be possible....

Comment: consider the interceptor get a request for `action1` which is not an ajax action. The `for` statement loops through all methods, it finds another action `action2` which IS an ajax method and returns true!! Is there any way I can find the exactly executed action method. So, the if statement will always be true,  for all actions `action1`, `action2` or `action3` if at least one of them have ajax action anotation.